# JMeter result in JTL format along with request and response data

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to get Jmeter output in JTL format so that I can utilize JMeter GUI to "View result tree" using "Read from file" option

I am running following command from cmd line

jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t nmame.jmx -l JmeterReports/TestReport.jtl

When I open the result file Testreport.jtl generated, I don't see request and response data. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to amend a little bit your command line in order to include some more [properties responsible for the results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -J jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true n -t nmame.jmx -l JmeterReports/TestReport.jtl
```

In order to make the change permanent add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: The problem is, I cannot generate both JTL and CSV reports as a result of execution. Only one report can be generated.
Futher, I  can generate HTML report only when we set Jmeter property - jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=’CSV’. 
3) But we can generated complete JTL report only when property value is set to ‘XML’.

Comment: This is not possible as per [current JMeter version 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) so I would suggest to keep `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format` as `csv`, if you need to additionally store request/response details consider adding [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) listener to your test plan and choose what and in which format you need to save

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to include entities that are available only if the output format is XML.

Hence, include below as part of your argument list

`-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml`

> items with (XML) only apply to XML format

**Source:**  https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_configuration

**Reference Screenshot**

[image]

You can still persist with .JTL file extensions for your log files and need not rename all of them to .XML. JMeter will still read the data and provide you with the necessary details

---

Hope this helps!